# line break within webhook

Tags: break, line-breaks, google-appsheet

I need to make line break within a webhook using concatenate sentence or & for an appsheet application
I've tried making brakes with ", &  UNICHAR(10) &, "\n", "\r", and other chr but no luck.
The thing is that the concatenate  " symbol with a linebreak works fine on a virtual column but not in the webhook.